# Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

can anyone can tell me how to fix this? it says user is not defined, thx

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for(var i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++){
    updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var productId = this.dataset.product
        var action = this.dataset.action
        console.log('productId:', productId, 'action:', action )

        console.log('USER:', user)
        if(user == 'AnonymousUser'){
            console.log('Not logged in')
            } else {
              updateUserOrder(productId, action)
       } })

}
```

Comment: In the provided code, the variable `user` just comes from nowhere, you've to define your users before using them.

Comment: add your html...

Answer (score 0):

In the Assumption that you are working on a Django project, you need to define the variable user...
In your script tag try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var user = '{{request.user}}';
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is very obvious error in your case. You have not defined `user` anywhere in your provided snippet. Please check if not provided then declare a variable `var user = '';` inside or outside `for` loop